# issues in table alias in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, alias

Here, I am creating an alias for the inner selection, but it automatically adds the table prefix to the alias table. My sql query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    `tb1`.*, `tb2`.*, `tb3`.`client_name`,
    `cms_tb4`.*,  `tb1`.`project_status` AS pstat
FROM
    (`cms_projects` tb1)
JOIN  `cms_project_type` tb2 ON `tb2`.`id` = `tb1`.`project_type`
JOIN  `cms_clients` tb3 ON `tb1`.`client_id` = `tb3`.`client_id`
JOIN  (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t1.project_id AS projid,
                 t2.work_id,
                t2.work_date
            FROM
                cms_projects_mod t1,
                cms_work_status_emp  t2
            WHERE
                t1.module_id = t2.pro_module_id
            ORDER BY
                t2.work_date DESC
        )  AS subtb4
    GROUP BY
        projid
    ORDER BY
        work_date DESC
) AS tb4 ON  `cms_tb4`.`projid` = `tb1`.`project_id`
LIMIT 50
```

i am working on codeigniter framework.

---

in codeigniter model just like this

```
         $this->db->select('tb1.*');
                $this->db->select('tb1.project_status as pstat');
                $this->db->from('cms_projects tb1');
               $this->db->join('project_type tb2', 'tb2.id=tb1.project_type');
             $this->db->join('clients tb3', 'tb1.client_id = tb3.client_id');
            $this->db->join("(
                       select * from (
              select t1.project_id as projid,                                     t2.work_id,t2.work_date from cms_projects_mod t1, cms_work_status_emp t2  where  t1.module_id = t2.pro_module_id order by  t2.work_date desc) as subtb4 
 group by  projid  order by  work_date desc ) as tb4 ",
"tb4.projid = tb1.project_id" ,false);
      $this->db->group_by("tb1.project_id");
            $this->db->order_by("tb3.work_date",'desc');
```

here i didn't give any prefix in third join tb4 but CI Add automatically when the running time.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current results, and an example of your expected results?

Comment: make sure that you have no prefix set in the database.php under config , it should look like this $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

Comment: actually the last alias tb4 its just only a view but its automatically add default table prefix and i want to avoid 'cms_' in 'cms_tb4'.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code order in CodeIgniter Documentation.

```
$this->db
   ->select()
   ->from()
   ->join()
```

This is the correct order. Changing the order sometimes causes issues in complex queries.

Visit this link https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2975

Comment: Thank you - this finally showed me what I was doing wrong! I was caching from/join/where, and then reusing that with different `select`s and kept getting table prefix errors. Once I rearranged the order to put select first, it worked. That meant I couldn't quite use native query caching anymore, but I was still able to split it into a reusable function.

Comment: You can troubleshoot this type of issue by getting the last executed query and figure it out. Join statements should be always in the end because of its dependency on alias names.

Answer (score -1):

Why you using query strings? If you using coeignoter why dont you use active record. Active Record queries are automatically protected with sql injection.
 you can do kind of this....its not same you want just idea how you can use active record sql.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*',FALSE)
                  ->from('tb1','tb2'.....)
                  ->join('tb2', 'tb1.cms_project_type = tb2.cms_project_type','left')
                  ->join('tb3', 'tb1.cms_project_type = tb2.cms_project_type','left')
                  ->group_by('projid')  
                  ->order_by('work_date','DESC') 
                  ->get();
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Hope this help.

Comment: he has nested select statements. You forgot to include that in your answer.

Comment: Note: If you intend to write your own queries you can disable this class in your database config file, allowing the core database library and adapter to utilize fewer resources.  see the doc here (the 1st pinky thing) https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html